# array definition and initiation in promela

Tags: promela

> ```
> 1 #define NUM_PHIL 4
> 2 
> 3 byte chopstick[4];
> 4 chopstick[0] = 1;
> 5 chopstick[1] = 1;
> 6 chopstick[2] = 1;
> 7 chopstick[3] = 1;
> 8 
> 9 proctype phil(int id) {
> 10    do 
> 11      ::printf("Philosopher %d is thinking\n",id);
> 12      /* ... */
> 13      printf("Philosopher %d is eating with forks %d and %d\n",id,id,(id+1)%4);
> 14      /* ... */
> 15    od
> 16    }
> 16a
> 17 init {
> 18    int i = 0; 
> 19    do 
> 20    :: i >= NUM_PHIL -> break
> 21    :: else -> run phil(i); 
> 22               i++ 
> 23    od 
> 24    }
> ```

the codes above send an error "syntax error saw 'an identifier' near 'chopstick'"
how can i define and initialize array as a global variable outside the prototype P()
thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You would initialize the chopstick array in an `init` body.

```
#define NUM_PHIL 4

byte chopstick[4];    /* NUM_PHIL */

proctype phil (int n) { /* ... */ }

init {
  chopstick[0] = 1;
  /* ... */

  run phil (0);
  /* ... */
}
```